# .animate() acting weird (repeating animation) (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, repeat

If you visit http://ngmat.site90.net/ and hover your mouse over the little black box with text up in the upper-left corner it's supposed to enlarge to show all text. It does exactly what I want at the moment but it does it in a very strange way. It repeats the animation over and over again sometimes, well I guess you have to see it yourself as I have no clue why it's doing so.

edit: I used a little hack that I came up with to get the height of the div if the height would've been set to "auto", that may be the problem?

Here's the JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var idagHeight = parseInt($("#idag").css('height'));
    var idagWidth = parseInt($("#idag").css('width'));
    var idagPopUpLeft = parseInt($("#idagPopUp").css('left'));

    $("#idag").css({"height": "auto", "width": idagWidth+30});
    var idagTempHeight = $("#idag").height();
    $("#idag").removeAttr("style");


    $("#idag").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).animate({height: idagTempHeight, width: idagWidth+30}, 300);
        $("#idagPopUp").animate({left: idagPopUpLeft+30}, 300);
    });
    $("#idag").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).animate({height: idagHeight, width: idagWidth}, 300, function(){$("#idag").removeAttr("style");});
        $("#idagPopUp").animate({left: idagPopUpLeft}, 300);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var idagHeight = parseInt($("#idag").css('height'));
    var idagWidth = parseInt($("#idag").css('width'));
    var idagPopUpLeft = parseInt($("#idagPopUp").css('left'));

    $("#idag").hover(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({height: "+=30", width: "+=30"}, 300);
        $("#idagPopUp").stop().animate({left: "+=30"}, 300);
    }, function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({height: idagHeight, width: idagWidth}, 300);
        $("#idagPopUp").stop().animate({left: idagPopUpLeft}, 300);
    });
});
```

Or if you do not know the final block height you can change the very first animate function to:

```
$(this).stop().animate({width: "+=30"}, 300, function() {
    $(this).css("height", "auto");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

When you hover the childrens inside #idag, a mouseout event is triggered. Animating the div is getting the mouse out from the childrens, so a mouseover event is triggered again. 
You could prevent this using

```
e.cancelBubble = true;
if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
```

inside your handlers.

Also is a good practice to call .stop() before .animate() for preventing long queues of animations.